# How to import specific function from modules that are in the same path on PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

Every time I try to import specific function from the module it doesn't give me an error, instead it just outputs everything in the file as if I imported module. How do I solve this problem?

Thanks, please refer to the example below!

example.py

```
def make_pizza(*toppings):
    """Print the list of toppings that have been requested."""
     print(*toppings)
make_pizza('mushrooms')
make_pizza('pepperoni', 'extra cheese', 'olives')
print("Done!")

def name_list(*names):
    print(names)
name_list('molor', 'oyuka', 'maral', 'michid')
```

So if I call it like this: `from example import make_pizza`
it should output only `make_pizza`, right?

Comment: Show us a full example, in code, of your `module.py` and how you import it in the question itself by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65741691/edit).

Comment: @MolorerdeneErdene you should edit your question.

Comment: def function_name(name, age, **extra):

Comment: You can edit the question by pressing the button that says `Edit` or pressing [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65741691/edit)

Comment: Calling `from example.py import make_pizza` is not correct as it should be `from example import make_pizza`. But it seems like you're calling the function at module level in `example.py`, which means that it will be called when you're importing from the module. Also, please remove all the # from your text. The explaining text that existed before was fine.

Comment: Thank you, but i did no include .py when i called it. example:  from example import example

Answer (score 1):

When you import something, it essentially runs the file and takes whatever function you need.

```
# main.py

from example import make_pizza  # runs example.py which prints stuff

make_pizza(...)  # now you can use the imported function
```

To prevent printing when you import `example.py`, use `if __name__ == '__main__'`, which prevents the stuff inside from being run when you aren't actually running the file (when you are importing a function)

```
def make_pizza(*toppings):
    """Print the list of toppings that have been requested."""
     print(*toppings)

def name_list(*names):
    print(names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_pizza('mushrooms')
    make_pizza('pepperoni', 'extra cheese', 'olives')
    print("Done!")
    name_list('molor', 'oyuka', 'maral', 'michid')
```

Comment: With that method now the output is nothing  . No errors either just empty output.

Comment: @MolorerdeneErdene You have to call the function after you've imported it.